# Image resizing not working if height and width values are different

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, image-resizing

I am trying below code to resize height and width of image. If i give **resize(350 ,250)** instead of resizing ,  its displaying image **350px away from left** and **250px away from top** from its original position.

If i give **same value** for both height and width [ **resize(250 ,250)** ] , than only resize will work properly.

```
<?php $imageUrl = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(250 ,250)->setQuality(100); ?>
```

**Update**

Issue is if we resize the Image with Different height & Width , than its adding background image to [Product image](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-mugs-1.html).

1) [resize(150 ,750) Image with differnet height and width: link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/150x750/0dc2d03fe217f8c83829496872af24a0/8/9/890.png)

2) [resize(750, 750) Image with same height and width: link2](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/750x750/0dc2d03fe217f8c83829496872af24a0/8/9/890.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resize image Height or Width by use below code

```
<?php $imageUrl = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->keepFrame(true)->resize(350 ,250)->setQuality(100); ?>
```

Comment: thanks, but still its giving me same result......

Comment: Which page you want to need resize image?

Comment: in Product view page, you can see in [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/750x750/0dc2d03fe217f8c83829496872af24a0/8/9/890.png) with same height and width & in [link2](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/750x250/0dc2d03fe217f8c83829496872af24a0/8/9/890.png) with different height and width.....

Comment: In which file you have put this code?

Comment: in view.phtml file.....

Comment: You need to write your code in app/design/frontend/YourTheme/ThemePackdge/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml

Comment: Main Product image code is present in Media.phtml file, i am trying to display same image one more time with desired height and width in [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-mugs-1.html) so only i am trying in View.phtml......

Comment: I have testes this code in view.phtml and works for me. Can you add your image code which you have used or try again with clear magento cache.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61142/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-s-h-patel).